Vite Vue 3 Vuetify Could not find layout item "layout-item-0"
Setup layout
default.ts:
<VApp>
   <VMain>
     <VAppBar class="navbar" elevation="10"></VAppBar>
     <VContainer
       fluid
       class="fill-viewport"
     >
       <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />
     </VContainer>
   </VMain>
</VApp>

RouterView render page:
<VAppBar density="comfortable" flat>
   <VAppBarTitle>
      Task Status
   </VAppBarTitle>
</VAppBar>

<VTable></VTable>

Error: [Vuetify] Could not find layout item "layout-item-0"
How to resolve it?

Is there no stack trace for the error?  Is "layout-item-0" something you've defined somewhere?  The code shown does not reproduce the issue by itself.  please provide mcve
